# object of "ESPAsyncWebServer" causing conflict

Tags: c++, esp32, platformio

I have been trying to develop multi cpp project in platformio and whenever I define ESPAsyncWebServer class object with the extern in defines.h and declare it in main.cpp I am getting scarry looking error 'HTTP_DELETE' conflicts with a previous declaration But when I define ESPAsyncWebServer class object without the extern in main.cpp instead I am not getting any error. Can you help in this regard?

main.cpp:

```
#include "defines.h"
#include <AsyncMQTT_ESP32.h>
#include <WebServer_ESP32_W5500.h>

AsyncMqttClient mqttClient;
TimerHandle_t mqttReconnectTimer;
TimerHandle_t wifiReconnectTimer;

/* ESPAsyncWebServer */
WiFiClient clientWiFi;
AsyncWebServer serverAsyncWeb(80);
AsyncWebSocket WebSocketAsync("/ws");
/* Processors */

String prc(const String &var)
{
  return String();
}

/* Processors End */
void allAsyncWebServer()
{
  serverAsyncWeb.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request)
                    { request->send(SPIFFS, "/index.htm", String(), false, prc); }); /// log
}

/* allAsyncWebServer End */

/* WebSocketAsync */

void AsyncWebSocketEvent(AsyncWebSocket *server, AsyncWebSocketClient *client, AwsEventType type, void *arg, uint8_t *data, size_t len)
{
  switch (type)
  {
  case WS_EVT_CONNECT:
    Serial.printf("WebSocket client #%u connected from %s\n", client->id(), client->remoteIP().toString().c_str());
    break;
  case WS_EVT_DISCONNECT:
    Serial.printf("WebSocket client #%u disconnected\n", client->id());
    break;
  case WS_EVT_DATA:
    // handleWebSocketMessage(arg, data, len);
    break;
  case WS_EVT_PONG:
  case WS_EVT_ERROR:
    break;
  }
}





byte mac[][NUMBER_OF_MAC] =
{
  { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0x01 },
  { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xBE, 0x02 },
  { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0x03 },
  { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xBE, 0x04 },
  { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0x05 },
  { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xBE, 0x06 },
  { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0x07 },
  { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xBE, 0x08 },
  { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0x09 },
  { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xBE, 0x0A },
  { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0x0B },
  { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xBE, 0x0C },
  { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0x0D },
  { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xBE, 0x0E },
  { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0x0F },
  { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xBE, 0x10 },
  { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0x11 },
  { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xBE, 0x12 },
  { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0x13 },
  { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xBE, 0x14 },
};

// Select the IP address according to your local network
IPAddress myIP(192, 168, 2, 232);
IPAddress myGW(192, 168, 2, 1);
IPAddress mySN(255, 255, 255, 0);

// Google DNS Server IP
IPAddress myDNS(8, 8, 8, 8);


extern "C"
{
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/timers.h"
}

const char *PubTopic = "async-mqtt/ESP32_W5500_Pub"; // Topic to publish

// ESP32_W5500 ETH;

void connectToWifi()
{
  Serial.println("Connecting to Wi-Fi...");
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
}

void connectToMqtt()
{
  Serial.println("Connecting to MQTT...");
  mqttClient.connect();
}

void WiFiEvent(WiFiEvent_t event)
{
  switch (event)
  {
#if USING_CORE_ESP32_CORE_V200_PLUS

  case ARDUINO_EVENT_WIFI_READY:
    Serial.println("WiFi ready");
    break;

  case ARDUINO_EVENT_WIFI_STA_START:
    Serial.println("WiFi STA starting");
    break;

  case ARDUINO_EVENT_WIFI_STA_CONNECTED:
    Serial.println("WiFi STA connected");
    break;

  case ARDUINO_EVENT_WIFI_STA_GOT_IP6:
  case ARDUINO_EVENT_WIFI_STA_GOT_IP:
    Serial.println("WiFi connected");
    Serial.print("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    connectToMqtt();
    break;

  case ARDUINO_EVENT_WIFI_STA_LOST_IP:
    Serial.println("WiFi lost IP");
    break;

  case ARDUINO_EVENT_WIFI_STA_DISCONNECTED:
    Serial.println("WiFi lost connection");
    xTimerStop(mqttReconnectTimer, 0); // ensure we don't reconnect to MQTT while reconnecting to Wi-Fi
    xTimerStart(wifiReconnectTimer, 0);
    break;
#else

  case SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP:
    Serial.println("WiFi connected");
    Serial.println("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    connectToMqtt();
    break;

  case SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_DISCONNECTED:
    Serial.println("WiFi lost connection");
    xTimerStop(mqttReconnectTimer, 0); // ensure we don't reconnect to MQTT while reconnecting to Wi-Fi
    xTimerStart(wifiReconnectTimer, 0);
    break;
#endif

  default:
    break;
  }
}

void ETH_event(WiFiEvent_t event)
{
  switch (event)
  {
#if USING_CORE_ESP32_CORE_V200_PLUS

  case ARDUINO_EVENT_ETH_START:
    Serial.println("ETH starting");
    break;

  case ARDUINO_EVENT_ETH_CONNECTED:
    Serial.println("ETH connected");
    break;

  case ARDUINO_EVENT_ETH_GOT_IP:
    Serial.println("ETH got IP");
    Serial.print("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(ETH.localIP());
    connectToMqtt();
    break;

  case ARDUINO_EVENT_ETH_DISCONNECTED:
    Serial.println("ETH lost connection");

    // ensure we don't reconnect to MQTT when no ETH
    xTimerStop(mqttReconnectTimer, 0);

    break;

  case ARDUINO_EVENT_ETH_STOP:
    Serial.println("ETH stops");

    // ensure we don't reconnect to MQTT when no ETH
    xTimerStop(mqttReconnectTimer, 0);

    break;
#else

  case SYSTEM_EVENT_ETH_CONNECTED:
    erial.println(F("ETH Connected"));
    break;

  case SYSTEM_EVENT_ETH_GOT_IP:
    Serial.println("ETH connected");
    Serial.println("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(ETH.localIP());
    connectToMqtt();
    break;

  case SYSTEM_EVENT_ETH_DISCONNECTED:
  case SYSTEM_EVENT_ETH_STOP:
    Serial.println("ETH lost connection");

    // ensure we don't reconnect to MQTT when no ETH
    xTimerStop(mqttReconnectTimer, 0);

    break;
#endif

  default:
    break;
  }
}

void printSeparationLine()
{
  Serial.println("************************************************");
}

void onMqttConnect(bool sessionPresent)
{
  Serial.print("Connected to MQTT broker: ");
  Serial.print(MQTT_HOST);
  Serial.print(", port: ");
  Serial.println(MQTT_PORT);
  Serial.print("PubTopic: ");
  Serial.println(PubTopic);

  printSeparationLine();
  Serial.print("Session present: ");
  Serial.println(sessionPresent);

  uint16_t packetIdSub = mqttClient.subscribe(PubTopic, 2);
  Serial.print("Subscribing at QoS 2, packetId: ");
  Serial.println(packetIdSub);

  mqttClient.publish(PubTopic, 0, true, "ESP32_W5500 Test");
  Serial.println("Publishing at QoS 0");

  uint16_t packetIdPub1 = mqttClient.publish(PubTopic, 1, true, "test 2");
  Serial.print("Publishing at QoS 1, packetId: ");
  Serial.println(packetIdPub1);

  uint16_t packetIdPub2 = mqttClient.publish(PubTopic, 2, true, "test 3");
  Serial.print("Publishing at QoS 2, packetId: ");
  Serial.println(packetIdPub2);

  printSeparationLine();
}

void onMqttDisconnect(AsyncMqttClientDisconnectReason reason)
{
  (void)reason;

  Serial.println("Disconnected from MQTT.");

  if (ESP32_W5500_isConnected())
  {
    xTimerStart(mqttReconnectTimer, 0);
  }
}

void onMqttSubscribe(const uint16_t &packetId, const uint8_t &qos)
{
  Serial.println("Subscribe acknowledged.");
  Serial.print("  packetId: ");
  Serial.println(packetId);
  Serial.print("  qos: ");
  Serial.println(qos);
}

void onMqttUnsubscribe(const uint16_t &packetId)
{
  Serial.println("Unsubscribe acknowledged.");
  Serial.print("  packetId: ");
  Serial.println(packetId);
}

void onMqttMessage(char *topic, char *payload, const AsyncMqttClientMessageProperties &properties,
                   const size_t &len, const size_t &index, const size_t &total)
{
  (void)payload;

  Serial.println("Publish received.");
  Serial.print("  topic: ");
  Serial.println(topic);
  Serial.print("  qos: ");
  Serial.println(properties.qos);
  Serial.print("  dup: ");
  Serial.println(properties.dup);
  Serial.print("  retain: ");
  Serial.println(properties.retain);
  Serial.print("  len: ");
  Serial.println(len);
  Serial.print("  index: ");
  Serial.println(index);
  Serial.print("  total: ");
  Serial.println(total);
}

void onMqttPublish(const uint16_t &packetId)
{
  Serial.println("Publish acknowledged.");
  Serial.print("  packetId: ");
  Serial.println(packetId);
}

void setup()
{
  #define FORMAT_SPIFFS_IF_FAILED false
  Serial.begin(115200);
  if (!SPIFFS.begin(FORMAT_SPIFFS_IF_FAILED))
  {
    Serial.println(F("W0")); // W0: SPIFFS Mount Failed
    return;
  }

  while (!Serial && millis() < 5000)
    ;

  Serial.print("\nStarting FullyFeature_ESP32_W5500 on ");
  Serial.print(BOARD_NAME);
  Serial.println(" with " + String(SHIELD_TYPE));
  Serial.println(WEBSERVER_ESP32_W5500_VERSION);
  // Serial.println(ASYNC_MQTT_GENERIC_VERSION);

  AMQTT_LOGWARN(F("Default SPI pinout:"));
  AMQTT_LOGWARN1(F("SPI_HOST:"), ETH_SPI_HOST);
  AMQTT_LOGWARN1(F("MOSI:"), MOSI_GPIO);
  AMQTT_LOGWARN1(F("MISO:"), MISO_GPIO);
  AMQTT_LOGWARN1(F("SCK:"), SCK_GPIO);
  AMQTT_LOGWARN1(F("CS:"), CS_GPIO);
  AMQTT_LOGWARN1(F("INT:"), INT_GPIO);
  AMQTT_LOGWARN1(F("SPI Clock (MHz):"), SPI_CLOCK_MHZ);
  AMQTT_LOGWARN(F("========================="));
  wifiReconnectTimer = xTimerCreate("wifiTimer", pdMS_TO_TICKS(2000), pdFALSE, (void *)0,
                                    reinterpret_cast<TimerCallbackFunction_t>(connectToWifi));
  mqttReconnectTimer = xTimerCreate("mqttTimer", pdMS_TO_TICKS(2000), pdFALSE, (void *)0,
                                    reinterpret_cast<TimerCallbackFunction_t>(connectToMqtt));

  WiFi.onEvent(WiFiEvent);

  mqttClient.onConnect(onMqttConnect);
  mqttClient.onDisconnect(onMqttDisconnect);
  mqttClient.onSubscribe(onMqttSubscribe);
  mqttClient.onUnsubscribe(onMqttUnsubscribe);
  mqttClient.onMessage(onMqttMessage);
  mqttClient.onPublish(onMqttPublish);

  // mqttClient.setServer(MQTT_HOST, MQTT_PORT);

  ///////////////////////////////////

  // To be called before ETH.begin()
  WiFi.onEvent(ETH_event);

  // start the ethernet connection and the server:
  // Use DHCP dynamic IP and random mac
  uint16_t index = millis() % NUMBER_OF_MAC;

  // bool begin(int MISO_GPIO, int MOSI_GPIO, int SCLK_GPIO, int CS_GPIO, int INT_GPIO, int SPI_CLOCK_MHZ,
  //            int SPI_HOST, uint8_t *W5500_Mac = W5500_Default_Mac);
  // ETH.begin( MISO_GPIO, MOSI_GPIO, SCK_GPIO, CS_GPIO, INT_GPIO, SPI_CLOCK_MHZ, ETH_SPI_HOST );
  //  ETH.begin( MISO_GPIO, MOSI_GPIO, SCK_GPIO, CS_GPIO, INT_GPIO, SPI_CLOCK_MHZ, ETH_SPI_HOST, mac[index] );
  //  byte esp32Mac[] = WiFi.macAddress();
  Serial.print("WiFi.macAddress(): ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.macAddress());
  uint8_t baseMac[6];
  esp_read_mac(baseMac, ESP_MAC_WIFI_STA);
  // ETH.begin(MISO_GPIO, MOSI_GPIO, SCK_GPIO, CS_GPIO, INT_GPIO, SPI_CLOCK_MHZ, ETH_SPI_HOST, baseMac);
  test();
  Serial.print("index: ");
  Serial.println(index);
  Serial.print("ETH.macAddress(): ");
  Serial.println(ETH.macAddress());
  // Static IP, leave without this line to get IP via DHCP
  // bool config(IPAddress local_ip, IPAddress gateway, IPAddress subnet, IPAddress dns1 = 0, IPAddress dns2 = 0);
  // ETH.config(myIP, myGW, mySN, myDNS);

  ESP32_W5500_waitForConnect();
  connectToWifi();


  allAsyncWebServer();    // Enable ESP Asynchronous Servers
  serverAsyncWeb.begin(); // Start ESP Asynchronous Server
  /* Initiallize AsyncWebSocket */
  WebSocketAsync.onEvent(AsyncWebSocketEvent);
  serverAsyncWeb.addHandler(&WebSocketAsync);
  ///////////////////////////////////
}

void loop()
{
}
```

define.h:

```
/****************************************************************************************************************************
  defines.h
  AsyncMqttClient_Generic is a library for ESP32, ESP8266, Protenta_H7, STM32F7, etc. with current AsyncTCP support

  Based on and modified from :

  1) async-mqtt-client (https://github.com/marvinroger/async-mqtt-client)

  Built by Khoi Hoang https://github.com/khoih-prog/AsyncMqttClient_Generic
 ***************************************************************************************************************************************/

#ifndef defines_h
#define defines_h
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
#include <AsyncTCP.h>
#include <Update.h>
#include <ESPmDNS.h>
#include <SPIFFS.h>

#include "Test.h"
#include <AsyncMQTT_ESP32.hpp>
#include <WebServer_ESP32_W5500.hpp>
#include "w5500/esp32_w5500.h"
// Debug Level from 0 to 4
#define _ETHERNET_WEBSERVER_LOGLEVEL_       1
#define _ASYNC_MQTT_LOGLEVEL_               1

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Optional values to override default settings
// Don't change unless you know what you're doing
//#define ETH_SPI_HOST        SPI3_HOST
//#define SPI_CLOCK_MHZ       25

// Must connect INT to GPIOxx or not working
// #define INT_GPIO            21  //4

// #define MISO_GPIO           19
// #define MOSI_GPIO           23
// #define SCK_GPIO            18
// #define CS_GPIO             22  //5

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// #include <WebServer_ESP32_W5500.h>

/////////////////////////////////////////////

// Enter a MAC address and IP address for your controller below.
extern AsyncMqttClient mqttClient;
extern TimerHandle_t mqttReconnectTimer;
extern TimerHandle_t wifiReconnectTimer;
// extern ESP32_W5500 ETH;

// // extern WiFiClient clientWiFi;
// extern AsyncWebServer serverAsyncWeb;
// extern AsyncWebSocket WebSocketAsync;

#define NUMBER_OF_MAC      20



#define WIFI_SSID         "Digisol"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD     "12345678"

#define MQTT_HOST IPAddress(192, 168, 1, 2)
// #define MQTT_HOST         "broker.emqx.io"        // Broker address
#define MQTT_PORT 1883

#endif    //defines_h
```

Test.h:

```
#ifndef Test_H
#define Test_H
void test();
#endif
```

Test.cpp:

```
#include "defines.h"
void test()
{   
    uint8_t baseMac[6];
    esp_read_mac(baseMac, ESP_MAC_WIFI_STA);
    mqttClient.setServer(MQTT_HOST, MQTT_PORT);
    ETH.begin(MISO_GPIO, MOSI_GPIO, SCK_GPIO, CS_GPIO, INT_GPIO, SPI_CLOCK_MHZ, ETH_SPI_HOST, baseMac);
}
```

Error:

```
In file included from C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/libraries/WebServer/src/HTTP_Method.h:4,
                 from C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/libraries/WebServer/src/WebServer.h:30,
                 from .pio/libdeps/esp32dev/WebServer_ESP32_W5500/src/WebServer_ESP32_W5500.hpp:33,
                 from include/defines.h:24,
                 from src/Test.cpp:1:
C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/esp32/include/nghttp/port/include/http_parser.h:95:6: error: 'HTTP_DELETE' conflicts with a previous declaration
   XX(0,  DELETE,      DELETE)       \
      ^
C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/esp32/include/nghttp/port/include/http_parser.h:138:45: note: in definition of macro 'XX'
 #define XX(num, name, string) HTTP_##name = num,
                                             ^~~
C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/esp32/include/nghttp/port/include/http_parser.h:139:3: note: in expansion of macro 'HTTP_METHOD_MAP'
   HTTP_METHOD_MAP(XX)
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from include/defines.h:16,
                 from src/Test.cpp:1:
.pio/libdeps/esp32dev/ESP Async WebServer/src/ESPAsyncWebServer.h:64:3: note: previous declaration 'WebRequestMethod HTTP_DELETE'
   HTTP_DELETE  = 0b00000100,
   ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/libraries/WebServer/src/HTTP_Method.h:4,
                 from C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/libraries/WebServer/src/WebServer.h:30,
                 from .pio/libdeps/esp32dev/WebServer_ESP32_W5500/src/WebServer_ESP32_W5500.hpp:33,
                 from include/defines.h:24,
                 from src/Test.cpp:1:
C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/esp32/include/nghttp/port/include/http_parser.h:96:6: error: 'HTTP_GET' conflicts with a previous declaration
   XX(1,  GET,         GET)          \
      ^
C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/esp32/include/nghttp/port/include/http_parser.h:138:45: note: in definition of macro 'XX'
 #define XX(num, name, string) HTTP_##name = num,
                                             ^~~
C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/esp32/include/nghttp/port/include/http_parser.h:139:3: note: in expansion of macro 'HTTP_METHOD_MAP'
   HTTP_METHOD_MAP(XX)
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from include/defines.h:16,
                 from src/Test.cpp:1:
.pio/libdeps/esp32dev/ESP Async WebServer/src/ESPAsyncWebServer.h:62:3: note: previous declaration 'WebRequestMethod HTTP_GET'
   HTTP_GET     = 0b00000001,
   ^~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/libraries/WebServer/src/HTTP_Method.h:4,
                 from C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/libraries/WebServer/src/WebServer.h:30,
                 from .pio/libdeps/esp32dev/WebServer_ESP32_W5500/src/WebServer_ESP32_W5500.hpp:33,
                 from include/defines.h:24,
                 from src/Test.cpp:1:
C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/esp32/include/nghttp/port/include/http_parser.h:97:6: error: 'HTTP_HEAD' conflicts with a previous declaration
   XX(2,  HEAD,        HEAD)         \
      ^
C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/esp32/include/nghttp/port/include/http_parser.h:138:45: note: in definition of macro 'XX'
 #define XX(num, name, string) HTTP_##name = num,
                                             ^~~
C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/esp32/include/nghttp/port/include/http_parser.h:139:3: note: in expansion of macro 'HTTP_METHOD_MAP'
   HTTP_METHOD_MAP(XX)
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from include/defines.h:16,
                 from src/Test.cpp:1:
.pio/libdeps/esp32dev/ESP Async WebServer/src/ESPAsyncWebServer.h:67:3: note: previous declaration 'WebRequestMethod HTTP_HEAD'
   HTTP_HEAD    = 0b00100000,
   ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/libraries/WebServer/src/HTTP_Method.h:4,
                 from C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/libraries/WebServer/src/WebServer.h:30,
                 from .pio/libdeps/esp32dev/WebServer_ESP32_W5500/src/WebServer_ESP32_W5500.hpp:33,
                 from include/defines.h:24,
                 from src/Test.cpp:1:
C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/esp32/include/nghttp/port/include/http_parser.h:98:6: error: 'HTTP_POST' conflicts with a previous declaration
   XX(3,  POST,        POST)         \
      ^
C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/esp32/include/nghttp/port/include/http_parser.h:138:45: note: in definition of macro 'XX'
 #define XX(num, name, string) HTTP_##name = num,
                                             ^~~
C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/esp32/include/nghttp/port/include/http_parser.h:139:3: note: in expansion of macro 'HTTP_METHOD_MAP'
   HTTP_METHOD_MAP(XX)
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from include/defines.h:16,
                 from src/Test.cpp:1:
.pio/libdeps/esp32dev/ESP Async WebServer/src/ESPAsyncWebServer.h:63:3: note: previous declaration 'WebRequestMethod HTTP_POST'
   HTTP_POST    = 0b00000010,
   ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/libraries/WebServer/src/HTTP_Method.h:4,
                 from C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/libraries/WebServer/src/WebServer.h:30,
                 from .pio/libdeps/esp32dev/WebServer_ESP32_W5500/src/WebServer_ESP32_W5500.hpp:33,
                 from include/defines.h:24,
                 from src/Test.cpp:1:
C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/esp32/include/nghttp/port/include/http_parser.h:99:6: error: 'HTTP_PUT' conflicts with a previous declaration
   XX(4,  PUT,         PUT)          \
      ^
C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/esp32/include/nghttp/port/include/http_parser.h:138:45: note: in definition of macro 'XX'
 #define XX(num, name, string) HTTP_##name = num,
                                             ^~~
C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/esp32/include/nghttp/port/include/http_parser.h:139:3: note: in expansion of macro 'HTTP_METHOD_MAP'
   HTTP_METHOD_MAP(XX)
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from include/defines.h:16,
                 from src/Test.cpp:1:
.pio/libdeps/esp32dev/ESP Async WebServer/src/ESPAsyncWebServer.h:65:3: note: previous declaration 'WebRequestMethod HTTP_PUT'
   HTTP_PUT     = 0b00001000,
   ^~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/libraries/WebServer/src/HTTP_Method.h:4,
                 from C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/libraries/WebServer/src/WebServer.h:30,
                 from .pio/libdeps/esp32dev/WebServer_ESP32_W5500/src/WebServer_ESP32_W5500.hpp:33,
                 from include/defines.h:24,
                 from src/Test.cpp:1:
C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/esp32/include/nghttp/port/include/http_parser.h:139:3: note: in expansion of macro 'HTTP_METHOD_MAP'
   HTTP_METHOD_MAP(XX)
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from include/defines.h:16,
                 from src/main.cpp:1:
.pio/libdeps/esp32dev/ESP Async WebServer/src/ESPAsyncWebServer.h:68:3: note: previous declaration 'WebRequestMethod HTTP_OPTIONS'
   HTTP_OPTIONS = 0b01000000,
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/libraries/WebServer/src/HTTP_Method.h:4,
                 from C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/libraries/WebServer/src/WebServer.h:30,
                 from .pio/libdeps/esp32dev/WebServer_ESP32_W5500/src/WebServer_ESP32_W5500.hpp:33,
                 from include/defines.h:24,
                 from src/main.cpp:1:
C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/esp32/include/nghttp/port/include/http_parser.h:128:6: error: 'HTTP_PATCH' conflicts with a previous declaration
   XX(28, PATCH,       PATCH)        \
      ^~
C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/esp32/include/nghttp/port/include/http_parser.h:138:45: note: in definition of macro 'XX'
 #define XX(num, name, string) HTTP_##name = num,
                                             ^~~
C:/Users/shubh/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/tools/sdk/esp32/include/nghttp/port/include/http_parser.h:139:3: note: in expansion of macro 'HTTP_METHOD_MAP'
   HTTP_METHOD_MAP(XX)
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from include/defines.h:16,
                 from src/main.cpp:1:
.pio/libdeps/esp32dev/ESP Async WebServer/src/ESPAsyncWebServer.h:66:3: note: previous declaration 'WebRequestMethod HTTP_PATCH'
   HTTP_PATCH   = 0b00010000,
   ^~~~~~~~~~
Compiling .pio\build\esp32dev\liba04\AsyncMQTT_ESP32\AsyncMqttClient\Packets\ConnAckPacket.cpp.o
Compiling .pio\build\esp32dev\liba04\AsyncMQTT_ESP32\AsyncMqttClient\Packets\Out\Connect.cpp.o
*** [.pio\build\esp32dev\src\Test.cpp.o] Error 1
*** [.pio\build\esp32dev\src\main.cpp.o] Error 1
=========================== [FAILED] Took 10.22 seconds ===========================
```

Comment: Look at the pre-compiled code in your temp folder, in a sub-folder named something like `arduino_build_513965/sketch/project_name.cpp`; Arduino does a lot of code "helping" just before compilation, so it's often helpful to see the actual code that's causing the error.